# Integration with Zendesk

Tags: integration, case

Is it possible to create tickets on Zendesk from Salesforce? I know we can create a ticket on Zendesk and it will be created on SF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. Here is some information about setting up the Zendesk integration if you don’t already have it.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038232533-Setting-up-the-Zendesk-for-Salesforce-integration

This article explains how to create new tickets.

https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038191674-Using-Ticket-View-in-Salesforce#topic_xkm_r1r_pjb